# Forgotpassword: wrong url in reset password e-mail

Tags: password

I have a forgotpassword form on my front-end. This works and generates reset password e-mails. But the reset url leads not to the front-end, but to the back-end.

What I've already tried to fix the problem:

- setpassword template on the front-end (setpassword.html)
- route setpassword to setpassword.html

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the problem: The test account had control panel privileges and was therefore redirected to the control panel set password page. This behaviour makes absolutely sense.

Answer (score 2):

Try checking out this config setting http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#setPasswordPath

Add your path in the craft/config/general.php

```
return array(
    'setPasswordPath' => 'login/set-password' // or wherever your template is
);
```